# warning c4307 integral constant overflow in C

Tags: c++, c, variables, compiler-errors, largenumber

I have this operation (8 * (512 * 786432)) and the product is 3221225472

I tried to use it with variables like longlong, unsigned long

But the compiler throw me an error

c4307 integral constant overflow

and I need the result for use it with functions, how can I fix it? or what variables can work for large numbers?

regards

Answer (score 22):

The expression `(8 * (512 * 786432))` has type `int` and it will overflow on 32-bit systems.  Assigning it to a variable of type `long` does not change the fact that the value has *already overflowed*.  You can fix this by annotating the numbers.

```
long x = (8L * (512L * 786432L));
```

You only need to put the `L` on one of the numbers, since it will force results to also have type `long`.

This assumes that `long` is 64-bit, which is true on most systems but not Windows.  You will need `LL` (or `i64`) on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use

```
(8 * (512ull * 786432))
```